# Exibir somente telefone fixo e celulares com digito 9 na frente

Tags: mysql, sql-select

Seguinte

Tenho uma tabela chamada `telefonia_numero` e dentro dela há um campo chamado `Numero` onde contém todos telefone do usuário.

> Ex . Jose - Numero 81 3636-1145, 81 99873-7787 e 9873-7787,

Ai vem o que eu quero.

Eu quero pegar somente o *telefone fixo* e o *telefone celulares* que tenha o digito 9 na frente *ex.( 81 99873-7787).* E ficaria de fora o que um nove a menus na frente *Ex (9873-7787)* então pegaria os telefone fixo e o telefones novos com digito 9 na frente.

Comment: Os telefones desse campo estão separados por vírgula? qual banco de dados está usando?

Comment: os telefone estão dessa forma 81 3636-1145

Comment: e o bando de dados phpmyadmim e não estão separados com virgula não

Answer (score 0):

Pode usar as funções  `replace()` e `char_length()` do MySQL para subustituir o espaço em branco e por nada e contar o número de caracteres do telefone e verificar se ele tem 11 dígitos no `WHERE` dessa forma:

```
//O primeiro parênteses verifica se é celular
SELECT * FROM telefones
WHERE (substr(replace(telefone, ' ', ''), 3,1) = 9 AND
CHAR_LENGTH(REPLACE(telefone, ' ', '')) = 12) OR CHAR_LENGTH(REPLACE(telefone, ' ', '')) = 11
```

Comment: rray esse select estar trazendo os numero fixo 81 3636-1145 com 11 caracteres e celulares que tem 11 caracteres 81 9873-8878. so quer eu quero que apareça o fixo com 11 caracteres ex 81 3636 - 1145 e celulares com 12 caracteres ex 81 99873-8878.

Comment: @user42804 o espaço não está sendo removido? a consulta deveria fazer isso. vc tem algum campo que identifique se o telefone é celular ou fixo? trocar `=` por `>=` resolve?

Comment: não tem nem um campo que identifique se é celular ou fixo!

Comment: @user42804 alterei a resposta veja se essa atende.

Comment: amigo rray - ainda esta trazendo os telefones celulares antigos ex 81 9873-8878. porém é para trazer somente os fixo ex 81 3636-1145 e celulares que tem o digito nove na frente ex 81 99873-8878. fico no aguardo e desde já te agradeço